# Cannot install e(fx)clipse in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I am trying to develop a desktop JavaFX application on Windows Vista 32-bit. For this I have installed Eclipse Luna and Java 8. Out of the box the following is underlined in red by eclipse as an error:

import com.sun.javafx.application.Application;

I found one of the solutions is to install e(fx)clipse. But when I go to

Help, Install New Software..., I select the Luna repository and then type e(fx)clipse as outlined on

http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html

but nothing shows up and cannot proceed.

What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

e(fx)clipse is not part of [Eclipse Luna (4.4)](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/luna). You need at least [Eclipse Mars (4.5)](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/mars), but for security and other reasons, you should not use outdated software.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cannot use anything newer because I've got an old 32-bit computer running Windows vista Home Premium. How can I use JavaFX on this computer then? Never mind that the software and computer is old, if I manage to install JavaFX I can them upload my code to GitHub and when I'll manage to get a new computer I will update what I need to update. Thanks.

Comment: In [Eclipse 2018-12 (4.10) the support for 32-bit Java has been dropped](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.10/platform.php#java32-removal). So Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9) with Java 8 (both 32-bit) should work on Windows Vista ([here is at least a bug report of Eclipse 4.7 on Windows Vista](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516892)). I guess it is possible to install the latest version of e(fx)clipse also into Eclipse 2018-09 (4.9). As tool e(fx)clipse helps you (but is not required) e. g. to edit FXML files. As framework e(fx)clipse can be used e. g. for OSGi-based applications.